# How to write an "overriding wrapper" for a function in FPATH?

Tags: linux, zsh, function

I use the expression "overriding wrapper" to refer to a function `foo` that overrides some original function falls, and calls this original function (or a copy of its) during its execution.

I have found Stack Exchange threads about this (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774538/override-a-shell-function-keep-a-reference-to-the-original-one)), but in my case I have the additional requirement that both the original `foo` as well as the overriding `foo` are meant to be accessible through `FPATH`, and autoloaded.  (The overriding version presumably would appear earlier in the search sequence, thus shadowing the original version.)

Is there a way to do this?

FWIW, in the particular scenario I'm dealing with, the overriding `foo` just assigns some none-standard values to some global variables that the original refers to for doing its thing.

Comment: Are you using Debian?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Both Debian and Centos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function to load the code of a function from a file in the same way that `autoload` does it, without the restriction that the file name has to match the function name.

```
## load_from FILE FUNCTION_NAME
load_from () {
  eval "$2 () { $(<$1) }"
}
```

Here's how the wrapper code looks like. `$^fpath/somefunction(N)` expands to the list of definitions of `somefunction` in the load path (`$^fpath/somefunction` expands to the list of `/dir/somefunction` for each `/dir` in `$fpath`, and the glob qualifier `(N)` restricts the expansion to existing files). Note that this only works if you have a single level of wrapper and the wrapper *is* in the fpath.

```
#autoload somefunction
local some_parameter=overridden_value
local autoload_files
autoload_files=($^fpath/somefunction(N))
load_from $autoload_files[2] somefunction_wrapped
somefunction_wrapped "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks!  Did you mean to call the function `autoload_from`?

Comment: Also, the expression `$fpath/somefunction(N[2])` is giving me trouble; I imaginge there's a typo in it somewhere, but I don't understand the syntax well enough to diagnose it.  FWIW, if I inspect trace generated with `set -x`, I see that the `$fpath/somefunction(N[2])` is getting replaced by my entire `$fpath` (space-separated).

Comment: @kjo My bad, I fixed some errors and added some explanations. I adapted this heavily from a function in my `.zshrc` (which autoloads from a directory not on `$fpath`, rather than from a subsequent directory on `$fpath` as in your case) and left a few mistakes in the adaptation.

Answer (score 2):

For replacing binaries/init.d files/scripts with a wrapper in Debian, I have used in production for years, with great success, file diversions.

If you just drop by a wrapper with the same name as the original file you want to shadow, what it happens is in the next update of the corresponding package the wrapper will be most probably rewritten by the file you intend to replace.

So for instance, for adding a wrapper for `gcc`, you would do:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /usr/bin/gcc.real /usr/bin/gcc
```

After that, you can place your wrapper at `/usr/bin/gcc`.

From then on, the old `gcc` binary will be `/usr/bin/gcc.real`, and most importantly, all the subsequent `gcc` future updates done/installed by Debian APT system, will install new instances of `/usr/bin/gcc` as `/usr/bin/gcc.real` and will leave your wrapper undisturbed.

See [Replacing binaries with dpkg-divert](https://debian-administration.org/article/118/Replacing_binaries_with_dpkg-divert)

From `man dpkg-divert`

> dpkg-divert is the utility used to set up and update the list of
>   diversions.
>
> File diversions are a way of forcing dpkg(1) not to install a file
>   into its location, but to a diverted location. Diversions can be used
>   through the Debian package scripts to move a file away when it causes
>   a conflict. System administrators can also use it to override some
>   package's configuration file, or whenever some files (which aren't
>   marked as “conffiles”) need to be preserved by dpkg, when installing a
>   newer version of a package which contains those files.

PS I used this technique for adding extra options to the `BIND` and `ISC-DHCP` init scripts.

Comment: I'm looking for something that does not depend on the distro, but, nonetheless, `dpkg-divert` does look like a very useful tool.  Thanks!